# How can I filter the dataframe according to priority based on column values using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe containing the name and profession priority 1,2 and 3.
I want to filter the dataframe according to priority.
First Director if it gets in first column should stop otherwise continue other columns.
Second actor  if it gets in first column should stop otherwise continue other columns

Input dataframe:

```
       primaryName      prof1     prof2   prof3
0     jordan belfort  producer     actor  writer
1    martin scorsese  producer  director   actor
2  leonardo dicaprio     actor  producer  writer
3         jonah hill     actor  producer  writer
```

Output dataframe

```
   primaryName
0 martin scorsese
1 leonardo dicaprio
2 jonah hill
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me.  Can you clarify a little bit and maybe add a little more complexity to your test data with expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes by first defining a categorical order of your profession. This assumes that the columns are ordered as shown.

```
cat = (pd.Categorical(['director','actor', 'writer', 'producer'], ordered=True)
         .reorder_categories(['director','actor', 'writer', 'producer'])
      )

# stack to be able to sort by column name
# then sort_values
new_df = (test_df.stack()
        .astype(cat).cat.codes
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values([0,'level_1'])
        .groupby('primaryName', as_index=False)
        .first()
)

# get the correct order by merge:
(test_df.merge(new_df, on='primaryName')
 .sort_values([0,'level_1'])['primaryName']
)
```

Output:

```
1      martin scorsese
2    leonardo dicaprio
3           jonah hill
0       jordan belfort
Name: primaryName, dtype: object
```